# Apple 's iPhone App Policy

Tags: iphone

I have read from some article that say's

Apple doesn't approve the application which Sell/Buy any physical items.

Is it correct or not ?

I am new to iPhone development.and don't know more details about Apples 's Policies.

Thanking in Advace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the amazon.com app. You can buy physical items using that app.

So, the answer is "not correct"

Comment: Indeed. Or the eBay app, for that matter

Comment: The statement refers to using the in-app purchasing functionality. In-app purchase cannot be used to sell physical items.